# Getting null file name in php - jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) by blueimp plugin for uploading files.

My client side options are

```
 dataType: 'json',
 autoUpload: true,
 formData: [],
 fileInput: $("#fileupload"),
 acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/i,
 maxFileSize: 999000,
 maxChunkSize: 0,
 multipart: false,
```

When I tried uploading files without the last two options, small files around(450 - 500 kb) were successfully uploaded and large files around (800 kb) were not. (request was sent, but the response never arrived. No errors were recorded on php or apache or javascript)

Then after adding the last two options, the response got me to the event of 'fileuploaddone' on client side, but was actually an erroneous response as I was getting file name as NULL on my backend-php and it shows me invalid file type.

I'm making api calls to php backend and when I do the same using postman(plugin in google chrome to make api calls), everything works fine.

P.S. my file name is transmitted via Content-Disposition header, but i'm not sure what it exactly is.